# How to implement pure virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, pure-virtual

Consider following example

```
#include <iostream>

struct PureVirtual {
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

struct FunctionImpl {
    virtual void Function() {
        std::cout << "FunctionImpl::Function()" << std::endl;
    }   
};

struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual {
    using FunctionImpl::Function;
};

int main() {
    NonPureVirtual c;
    c.Function();
}
```

Compiler (GCC 4.9, Clang 3.5) is exits with error

```
test.cpp:18:20: error: variable type 'NonPureVirtual' is an abstract class
    NonPureVirtual c;
                   ^
test.cpp:4:18: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'Function' in 'NonPureVirtual'
    virtual void Function() = 0;
             ^
```

But when I don't derive form `Pure Virtual` everything is OK. This is weird because Standard 10.4.4 says

> A class is abstract if it *contains or inherits at* least one *pure virtual function* for which the final overrider is *pure virtual*.

They are not saying anything about what the final overrider is but I suppose it should be `FunctionImpl::Function()` especially when I made it available through using directive. So why is still *Non Pure Virtual* abstract class and how can I fix this ?

Comment: It would seem you are confusing c++ with Java.  Just because FunctionImpl and PureVirtual each have methods of the same signature doesn't make one an implementation of the other.

Comment: I assume that this is an excerpt from a larger program and there it might be that the actual problem is the following: If you do not want to have PureVirtual twice as base class you have to inherit from it virtually (`public virtual PublicVirtual`). (Google for "virtual inheritance".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FunctionImpl::Function` and `PureVirtual::Function` are different functions from different classes.

Their respective types are `void (FunctionImpl::*)()` and `void (PureVirtual::*)()`.
Since PureVirtual and FunctionImpl are unrelated classes, these function types are unrelated.

They happen to have the same name and the same parameters and return type, but since they're different, the using FunctionImpl::Function line doesn't make that function an override of the one in PureVirtual.

And if you declared a variable of type `void (PureVirtual::*)()`, you wouldn't be able to assign FunctionImpl::Function to it.

In other words, the final override of PureVirtual::Function is the original one in PureVirtual, which is pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The following source code demonstrates my comment about virtual inheritance with an example. It compiles and runs fine.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct PureVirtual {
    virtual void Function() = 0;
};

struct FunctionImpl : public virtual PureVirtual {
    virtual void Function() {
        std::cout << "FunctionImpl::Function()" << std::endl;
    }   
};

struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public virtual PureVirtual {
    using FunctionImpl::Function;
};

int main() {
    NonPureVirtual c;
    c.Function();
}


/*
Local Variables:
compile-command: "g++ ./test.cc"
End:
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

When you derive from a pure virtual class you need to override all pure virtual functions if you want to create an instance of the class. The `FunctionImpl` is completely unrelated to `PureVirtual`

So

```
struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual {
    using FunctionImpl::Function;
};
```

is not enough, you need to implement void Function in the class NonPureVirtual

```
struct NonPureVirtual : public FunctionImpl, public PureVirtual {
    void Function() {}
};
```